# Which is quicker to manage a changing list of variables - a database, array, or text file?

Tags: php, sql, database, arrays, database-design

I have a function on a website where a user is able to register an email and in turn receive a unique 6 digit PIN.

I understand that if I generate a random number for the PIN, and then check it is unique against existing registered PINs (and if not then loop back), this will create quite a server load in later registrations.

Instead I have therefore elected to predefine the available PIN list, select a PIN from that list on registration, associate it with the user and then remove it from the available PIN list.

What is the most efficient way to handle the management of this list? Should I use a table in a database with an index, an array or just text files? As a guide I have 500,000 unique available PINs in my list.

At present, I have broken it down into text files, which I then cycle through to select available PINs and post each in turn to the database. When a PIN is used, it's deleted from the text file.

Is this best practice? Is there a faster/better way for handling a high volume of requests? What issues could I face trying to handle it this way?:

```
//getting pin list and file where the pin exists
$sel_file = "";
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
    $sel_file = "pinlist/".$i.".txt";
    $pin_list = file($sel_file);
    if(count($pin_list)!=0) {
        break;
    }
}

if(count($pin_list)==0) {
    echo "Sorry we are full";
    exit;
}

//selecting pin
$pin = $pin_list[0];

//deleting pin and saving file
unset($pin_list[0]);
file_put_contents($sel_file,implode("",$pin_list));

//insert data
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users(user_pin,user_email) VALUES('{$pin}','{$_POST['srEmail']}')");
```

**EDIT** : In answer to some of the comments; the PINs are unique access tokens for another program. The most important feature is the ability to handle concurrent requests to the list of available pins, so I assume that this excludes the flat txt file approach. Am I right that an array might still achieve this better than a standard database?

Comment: What sort of efficiency are you optimizing for?  Programmer time?  Execution time?  Disk space?

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: All of the above, but in priority: execution time, then disk space, then programming time.

Comment: You can't choose "all of the above".  That's one of the primary tenets of programming.

Comment: To clarify, when optimising the approach I ideally want to achieve the best possible state; low cost, fast response. What I meant thought is this needs to be fast above everything else, such that if I am handling very high volumes of requests it will be robust.

Comment: It also depends on your throughput. If you get one visitor every minute or less, a plain file in whatever form (serialized array or otherwise) is perfectly good enough. Any higher number of visitors will pretty much require a database though to deal with concurrent access.

Comment: Why does the PIN need to be unique? You're not using just the PIN to authenticate are you?

Comment: @AlexHowansky yes, the PINs are access tokens used in another program. They are only active when registered against an email.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, I think this is the critical point on reflection. The site could easily have concurrent users, so I assume a database is the easiest way for this. Would an array be a quicker use though and still achieve the same thing?

Comment: Where and how are you going to store "an array" that you keep taking things out of?

Comment: @alias51 Hard to say without knowing the details, but that seems like a really bad idea. Brute forcing a six digit PIN would take virtually no time or effort.